# My c++ file compiled with mingw32 successfully but not working what's problem?

Tags: c++, mingw32

I compiled c++ file with mingw32. It's compiled successfully but not working. What's the problem?

my command : x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o xx test.cpp

Comment: Probably a bug in your code.

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and compile with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -o xx test.cpp`

Comment: You have to tell us at least the symptoms: "not working" could mean anything from giving the wrong result, to crashing your computer. How exactly did you run it? What exactly happened? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: ***It's compiled successfully but not working. What's the problem?*** Most likely you have a bug in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Just because a program compiles does not in *any* way mean that it is free of errors. It only means that it is syntactically valid.

The compiler has no way of knowing your intentions, so it obviously cannot flag any logic errors in your code.

There are also a *lot* of things in C++ that are valid syntax but that you are not allowed to do and invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). The compiler is *not* required to flag such issues, *you* have to know all the rules and abide by them. If *any* part of your code contains UB, the compiler has no obligation to generate anything sensible for *any* parts of your program.

That something *compiles* means next to nothing as far as correctness goes. It's a *very* low bar.

Comment: No only the compiler is *not* required to flag all UB, but it can be proven that **the compiler cannot flag most undefined behavior** - [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem)